# inserting an array into table via direct SQL injection

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

There is an SQL error 3134 syntax error when trying to insert these arrays into the data table in Microsoft access 2016. I am unsure if it is due to the fact that they are arrays or if it is due to their variable types

Currently I am using the Record set method to insert into my table, however due to `.Update` not accepting duplicates into the table I would like to use direct SQL injection to be able to add in the data.

```
Dim SCR_Link_Array(), SCR_Number_Array(), SCR_Unit_Array(), SCR_EquipTag_Array(), _
SCR_SCI_Array(), SCR_Title_Array(), SCR_EquipFail_Array(), SCR_Facility_Array() As String
Dim SCR_DiscoveryDate_Array(), SCR_FileDate_Array(), SCR_OccurenceDate_Array() As Date
Dim SCR_RowCount, row, record, field As Integer


'array definition happens here

For record = 0 To SCR_RowCount - 1
    'This loop is for inserting lines into the DataBase table tblimportedSCRs
    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tblimportedSCRs(SCR #, Unit, System,Event Title,SCR Date,Date Occured,Discovery Date,Eq Fail,Facility) VALUES (" & SCR_Number_Array(record) & ", " & SCR_Unit_Array(record) & ", " & SCR_SCI_Array(record) & "," & SCR_EquipTag_Array(record) & "," & SCR_Title_Array(record) & "," & SCR_FileDate_Array(record) & "," & SCR_OccurenceDate_Array(record) & "," & SCR_DiscoveryDate_Array(record) & "," & SCR_EquipFail_Array(record) & "," & SCR_Facility_Array(record) & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL insertSQL

    Debug.Print (record)
 Next record
```

I would like this to insert properly into the table however whenever I run the `DoCmd.RunSQL insertSQL` the code encounters runtime error 3134.

Comment: I suspect you are conflating two concepts -- executing SQL statements directly against the database, and SQL injection. You really should get used to avoiding SQL injection, even in Access; [it's not that hard](https://bobby-tables.com/msaccess). But I would suggest your immediate issue is because of the spaces in the field name `SCR #` -- you need to wrap that in square brackets.

Comment: ah that's what I was missing, thanks a lot (I'm still getting used to VBA). I am also aware of lil' bobby tables. I am doing this because it is a closed database open only to upper management.

Comment: This isn't really a VBA issue; it's an SQL issue -- if you tried to issue the same SQL statement against an Access database (and presumably most other SQL-based databases) in other languages / environments, you'd have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> due to .Update not accepting duplicates into the table I would like
>   to use direct SQL

That won't make any difference.

If duplicates are not allowed, there is - by definition - no way to circumvent this.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't create the code, I am simply maintaining it. How would one prevent/remove the duplicate entries? because of the awkwardness of my predecessor the code will create duplicate entries if it fails

Comment: First look the value up. If it exists, abandon the insert; if not, go ahead.